# Get multiple child div texts on button click inside of parent div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple divs that have 3 div children each, 2 with the classes: name and email, and a button.

When any button inside the parent div is clicked, the text of the other children should be assigned to other 2 different divs with the ids #name and #email.

Something like this:

```
div1{name: john, email: john@email.com, button}
div2{name: karen, email: karen@email.com, button}

#name: --
#email: --
```

When I click div1's child button this should happen:

```
div1{name: john, email: john@email.com, button}
div2{name: karen, email: karen@email.com, button}

#name: john
#email: john@email.com
```

If possible, I would like a way to do it via javascript or jquery since I'm a begginer...

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do this :

```
$('div > button').on('click', function(){
  let emailVal = $(this).siblings('.email').text();
  $('#email').text(emailVal);
  let nameVal = $(this).siblings('.name').text();
  $('#name').text(nameVal);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!